# installing node-webcrypto-ossl on electron project in windows throws error

Tags: node.js, openssl, electron

I am trying to install a module that uses node-webcrypto-ossl in an electron project.

Below is my .npmrc file

```
target = 4.0.0
arch = x64
target_arch = x64
disturl=https://atom.io/download/electron
runtime = electron
build_from_source = true
openssl_dir = C:\OpenSSL-Win64
python = C:\Users\yalamber\AnacondaTwo\python.exe
```

Following is the error msg returned

```
win_delay_load_hook.cc
     Creating library D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\Release\nodessl.lib and object D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modu
  les\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\Release\nodessl.exp
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol OPENSSL_init_crypto [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.v
cxproj]
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol OPENSSL_init [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
key_exp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BIO_new_mem_buf [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vc
xproj]
key_exp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol i2d_PUBKEY_bio [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcx
proj]
key_exp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol d2i_PUBKEY_bio [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcx
proj]
key_exp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol i2d_PKCS8PrivateKeyInfo_bio [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\buil
d\nodessl.vcxproj]
key_exp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BIO_s_mem [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
key_exp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol d2i_PrivateKey_bio [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl
.vcxproj]
key_exp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BIO_ctrl [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
key_exp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BIO_new [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
scoped_ssl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nod
essl.vcxproj]
scoped_ssl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BN_CTX_free [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcx
proj]
scoped_ssl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BIO_free [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxpro
j]
scoped_ssl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EC_GROUP_free [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.v
cxproj]
scoped_ssl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_free [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.v
cxproj]
scoped_ssl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ECDSA_SIG_free [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.
vcxproj]
scoped_ssl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_MD_CTX_free [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl
.vcxproj]
scoped_ssl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EC_KEY_free [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcx
proj]
scoped_ssl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BN_free [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj
]
scoped_ssl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol RSA_free [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxpro
j]
scoped_ssl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_CTX_free [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodes
sl.vcxproj]
excep.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ERR_print_errors [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcx
proj]
digest.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_Digest [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
digest.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_MD_size [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj
]
rsa_gen.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BN_new [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
rsa_gen.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_assign [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vc
xproj]
rsa_gen.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BN_set_word [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxpro
j]
rsa_gen.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol RSA_new [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
rsa_gen.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_new [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxpr
oj]
rsa_gen.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol RSA_generate_key_ex [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodess
l.vcxproj]
rsa_jwk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_base_id [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.v
cxproj]
rsa_jwk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol RSA_set0_key [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxpr
oj]
rsa_jwk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol RSA_get0_crt_params [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodess
l.vcxproj]
rsa_jwk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol RSA_get0_factors [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.v
cxproj]
rsa_jwk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol RSA_set0_factors [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.v
cxproj]
rsa_jwk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.
vcxproj]
rsa_jwk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol RSA_get0_key [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxpr
oj]
rsa_jwk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol RSA_set0_crt_params [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodess
l.vcxproj]
rsa_jwk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BN_dup [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
rsa_pkcs1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_DigestVerifyInit [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nod
essl.vcxproj]
rsa_pkcs1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_DigestSignInit [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodes
sl.vcxproj]
rsa_pkcs1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_DigestVerifyFinal [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\no
dessl.vcxproj]
rsa_pkcs1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_DigestSignFinal [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\node
ssl.vcxproj]
rsa_pkcs1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_DigestUpdate [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl
.vcxproj]
rsa_pkcs1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_MD_CTX_new [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.v
cxproj]
rsa_oaep.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_CTX_new [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.
vcxproj]
rsa_oaep.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_CTX_ctrl [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl
.vcxproj]
rsa_oaep.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_encrypt [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.
vcxproj]
rsa_oaep.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CRYPTO_malloc [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcx
proj]
rsa_oaep.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_decrypt [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.
vcxproj]
rsa_oaep.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nod
essl.vcxproj]
rsa_oaep.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nod
essl.vcxproj]
ec_gen.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\no
dessl.vcxproj]
ec_gen.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EC_KEY_get0_group [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.v
cxproj]
ec_gen.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EC_GROUP_set_asn1_flag [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\node
ssl.vcxproj]
ec_gen.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EC_KEY_generate_key [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl
.vcxproj]
ec_dsa.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol i2d_ECDSA_SIG [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxpr
oj]
ec_dsa.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BN_bin2bn [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
ec_dsa.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ECDSA_SIG_new [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxpr
oj]
ec_dsa.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BN_num_bits [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj
]
ec_dsa.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ECDSA_SIG_set0 [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxp
roj]
ec_dsa.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BN_bn2binpad [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxpro
j]
ec_dsa.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CRYPTO_free [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj
]
ec_dsa.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ECDSA_SIG_get0 [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxp
roj]
ec_dsa.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodess
l.vcxproj]
ec_dsa.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol d2i_ECDSA_SIG [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxpr
oj]
ec_dsa.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EC_GROUP_get_order [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.
vcxproj]
ec_dh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EC_GROUP_get_degree [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.
vcxproj]
ec_dh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EC_KEY_get0_private_key [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\node
ssl.vcxproj]
ec_dh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EC_GROUP_get_curve_name [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\node
ssl.vcxproj]
ec_dh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_derive [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxp
roj]
ec_dh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_derive_init [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl
.vcxproj]
ec_dh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EC_KEY_get0_public_key [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodes
sl.vcxproj]
ec_dh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_PKEY_derive_set_peer [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nod
essl.vcxproj]
ec_dh.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ECDH_compute_key [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcx
proj]
ec_jwk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\
nodessl.vcxproj]
ec_jwk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BN_CTX_new [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
ec_jwk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EC_KEY_new [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
ec_jwk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EC_KEY_set_group [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vc
xproj]
ec_jwk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BN_CTX_get [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
ec_jwk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EC_POINT_get_affine_coordinates_GFp [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-os
sl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
ec_jwk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EC_KEY_set_private_key [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\node
ssl.vcxproj]
ec_jwk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EC_KEY_set_public_key_affine_coordinates [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcryp
to-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
aes_gen.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol RAND_bytes [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj
]
aes_ecb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_aes_256_ecb [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vc
xproj]
aes_ecb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_CipherFinal_ex [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl
.vcxproj]
aes_ecb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_aes_192_ecb [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vc
xproj]
aes_ecb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_CipherInit_ex [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.
vcxproj]
aes_ecb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_aes_128_ecb [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vc
xproj]
aes_ecb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_CipherUpdate [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.v
cxproj]
aes_ecb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl
.vcxproj]
aes_cbc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AES_set_decrypt_key [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodess
l.vcxproj]
aes_cbc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AES_wrap_key [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxpr
oj]
aes_cbc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_aes_192_cbc [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vc
xproj]
aes_cbc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_aes_128_cbc [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vc
xproj]
aes_cbc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AES_set_encrypt_key [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodess
l.vcxproj]
aes_cbc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AES_unwrap_key [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcx
proj]
aes_cbc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_aes_256_cbc [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vc
xproj]
aes_gcm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_aes_128_gcm [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vc
xproj]
aes_gcm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_EncryptUpdate [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.
vcxproj]
aes_gcm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_aes_256_gcm [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vc
xproj]
aes_gcm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodess
l.vcxproj]
aes_gcm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_EncryptFinal_ex [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodess
l.vcxproj]
aes_gcm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_DecryptInit_ex [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl
.vcxproj]
aes_gcm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_EncryptInit_ex [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl
.vcxproj]
aes_gcm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_DecryptFinal_ex [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodess
l.vcxproj]
aes_gcm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_aes_192_gcm [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vc
xproj]
aes_gcm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_CIPHER_block_size [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\node
ssl.vcxproj]
aes_gcm.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_DecryptUpdate [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.
vcxproj]
aes_ctr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CRYPTO_ctr128_encrypt [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\node
ssl.vcxproj]
aes_ctr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol AES_encrypt [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxpro
j]
hmac_sign.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol HMAC [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
pbkdf2_derive.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\no
dessl.vcxproj]
common.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BN_bn2bin [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
w_key.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol RSA_size [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
w_key.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol EVP_get_digestbyname [D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl
.vcxproj]
D:\ZKPKI\desktop-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\Release\nodessl.node : fatal error LNK1120: 116 unresolved externals [D:\ZKPKI\desk
top-app\node_modules\node-webcrypto-ossl\build\nodessl.vcxproj]
```

I am not sure what the error is all about but this module fails to compile only when using electron, it installs and compiles fine with just node.

Answer (score 1):

It compiled properly after I added

openssl_1_0_2 = 1

to .npmrc